# Is it possible to pass in auto_increment for the parameter datatype in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

create procedure add_fighter(
in p_fighter_id int auto_increment
, in p_fighter_name varchar(50)
, in p_country_of_origin varchar(2)
, in p_fighter_age int
, in p_UFC_debut int
)
begin
declare mess varchar(70);

```
-- check if fighter_id is empty
if p_fighter_id = '' then
set mess = 'please enter the fighter_id';
end if;
-- check if fighter_name is empty
if p_fighter_name = '' then
set mess = 'please enter the figher_name';
end if;

if p_country_of_origin = '' then
set mess = 'please enter the fighter''''s country_of_origin';
end if;

if p_fighter_age = '' then
set mess = 'please enter the fighter''s'' age';
end if;

if p_UFC_debut = '' then
set mess = 'please enter the fighter''''s UFC_debut year';
end if;

if p_fighter_name not like '% %' then
set mess = 'please enter the fighter''''s full name';
end if;

if counrty_of_origin not like '%__%' then
set mess = 'please use the 2 letter abbreviation of the country';
end if;


insert into fighters(
     fighter_id 
    ,fighter_name 
    ,country_of_origin
    ,fighter_age 
    ,UFC_debut 
    )
    values(
        p_fighter_id 
        ,p_fighter_name 
        ,p_country_of_origin
        ,p_fighter_age 
        ,p_UFC_debut 
        );
```

Comment: I'm not sure why not all the code was included in the body. The parameter is in the header just before the code.

Comment: `auto_increment` is column attribute - it cannot be used as SP parameter atttribute... Set `fighters.fighter_id` as autoinctemented and remove it from your SP at all - from INSERT query (both columns list and parameters) and from SP parameters.

Comment: From the other side your SP is unclear. What's the reason to define and set `mess` variable if you do not use it at all except assigning? What's the reason to test values if you perform INSERT anycase? PS. Read [messages formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: This is application code. Is this an assignment to, for some reason, do this all in MySQL?

Comment: I am trying to be able to add a record to the fighters table by calling the stored procedure. The table already has an autoincremented attribute for the fighter_id field. When I call the procedure and pass in the parameters for a new record I get an error message. Also I tried removing the auto_increment attribute from the SP and got a different error when passing in parameters for a new record.

Comment: Please publish the table definition, the call statement which throws an error and the full error message , all as text to the question.